# Python - Converting Characters to a Bitstring

Tags: python-3.x, ascii

This *is* for a homework assignment, but I have put work into my solution and am not sure where I am getting an error. Here is what I am supposed to do:

1. Add 1 to each character’s numeric ASCII value.
2. Convert it to a bit string.
3. Shift the bits of the string one place to the left.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
message = input("Enter a message: ")
ordstore = 0

for ch in message:
    ordstore = ord(ch) + 1
    bstring = ""
    while ordstore > 0:
        remainder = ordstore % 2
        ordstore = ordstore // 2
        bstring = str(remainder) + bstring

#print(bstring)

if(len(bstring) > 0):
    move1 = bstring[0]
    new_string = bstring[1:]
    new_string += move1

print(new_string)
```

My problem is that I am overwriting the values that I store in the first for loop. My initial thought to fix it was to use:

```
ordstore = ord(ch) += 1
```

However, that doesn't fix my problem either.

Any help or guidance is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a temporary variable in your second loop so that you can break that apart instead of your ordstore variable.

```
for ch in message:
    ordstore = ord(ch) + 1
    bstring = ""
    tempordstore = ordstore 
    while tempordstore > 0:
        remainder = tempordstore % 2
        tempordstore = tempordstore // 2
        bstring = str(remainder) + bstring
```

But even here your `bstring` is replaces for each `ch in message`.  Perhaps taking it outside so you just keep adding to the `bstring`?

```
bstring = ""
for ch in message:
    ordstore = ord(ch) + 1
    tempordstore = ordstore 
    while tempordstore > 0:
        remainder = tempordstore % 2
        tempordstore = tempordstore // 2
        bstring = str(remainder) + bstring
```

This way your `bstring` is not just based on the final character of message.